# How can i set an integer variable using stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

exec SP_HastaIcmal_AktifKaliciHastalar 25
it returns 86.

```
DECLARE @iAktifKaliciHastalar int

SET @iAktifKaliciHastalar = exec SP_HastaIcmal_AktifKaliciHastalar 25
```

that code return error.

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @iAktifKaliciHastalar int

EXEC @iAktifKaliciHastalar = SP_HastaIcmal_AktifKaliciHastalar 25
```

This should work fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the value is returned as a return code from the sproc (i.e. RETURN 86), then:

```
DECLARE @iAktifKaliciHastalar int
exec @iAktifKaliciHastalar = SP_HastaIcmal_AktifKaliciHastalar 25
```

If it's being returned as a resultset, I'd recommend changing it to being returned as a return code like above, or as an OUTPUT param (return codes can only be integers), as long as it's only ever going to return a single value.

Comment: DECLARE @iAktifKaliciHastalar int 
exec @iAktifKaliciHastalar = SP_HastaIcmal_AktifKaliciHastalar 25 
print @iAktifKaliciHastalar

return 86 from sp but print 0

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to the `EXEC @var = ProcName` solutions, you could use output parameters which means changing your stored proc of course

```
DECLARE @iAktifKaliciHastalar int

EXEC SP_HastaIcmal_AktifKaliciHastalar 25, iAktifKaliciHastalar OUTPUT
```